# How to solve Scala compiler's "class X inherits different type instances of class Y[Z]" error?

Tags: scala, parent-child, multiple-inheritance, traits

Given the following code:

```
sealed abstract class Foobar[+Parent <: Foobar[Parent]](parent: Option[Parent])

trait Foo[+Parent <: Foobar[Parent]] extends Foobar[Foo[Parent]]

trait Bar[+Parent <: Foobar[Parent]] extends Foobar[Bar[Parent]]

class Raboof[+Parent <: Foobar[Parent]](val parent: Foo[Parent]) extends Foobar(Some(parent)) with Foo[Parent] with Bar[Parent]
```

How to solve this inheritance issue in Scala's type system?

Motivation: The hypothetical traits `Foo` and `Bar` would implement methods that shall be provided by several classes such as the class `Raboof` mixing in these traits.

The Scala Worksheet of Scala-SDK Version 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe complains about the following:

```
illegal inheritance;  class Raboof inherits different type instances of class Foobar: scrap.Foobar[scrap.Bar[Parent]] and scrap.Foobar[scrap.Foo[Parent]]
```

The different type instances `scrap.Foobar[scrap.Bar[Parent]]` and `scrap.Foobar[scrap.Foo[Parent]]` should dissolve into a single type. In my understanding into `scrap.Foobar[scrap.Raboof[Parent]]` because the class `Raboof` is mixing in both the traits `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition works:

```
class Raboof[+Parent <: Foobar[Parent]](val parent: Raboof[Parent]) extends 
  Foobar[Raboof[Parent]](Some(parent)) with Foo[Parent] with Bar[Parent]
```

Your original definition:

1. doesn't tell Scala how to combine `Foobar[Foo[Parent]]` and `Foobar[Bar[Parent]]`. Since `Foobar[Raboof[Parent]]` is a subtype of both, this works.
2. Has the wrong type for `val parent`, since `Foobar[Bar[Parent]]` requires `parent: Bar[Parent]]`.